# Audio synthesis on Android?

Tags: android, audio, sound-synthesis

I would like to create some instruments for Android using generative audio. I really like SuperCollider, but it doesn't seem to be that far along for Android. Are there any good libraries or techniques for programming audio? I have seen at least two apps in Market which seem to use generative audio. This, for example:

http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-etherophone-DEBE.aspx

Another possibility is just importing separate audio files for each note...but that seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

http://gitorious.org/pdlib/pages/PdForAndroid

I think this suits my needs, so that answers it.